# Facebook API for conversations

Tags: facebook, api, message

Me and my friends are frequently using a Facebook group chat conversation. I'm building a web app that allows them to login with Facebook and do some silly stuff. Is there any way I can add that specific Facebook conversation so they can chat while on the website just like they would on facebook? I checked the API but didn't really find any references to this

Has anyone done stuff like this?

Answer (score 0):

The Chat API is deprecated, it is impossible to do that.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat